# DataTable select distinct values from several columns

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, datatable

as allways i need your help :)

i got a `DataTable` which has the following columns:

`TITLE ADDRESS BRANCH BRANCH1 BRANCH2 BRANCH3`

since i dont want to execute another MySql query to get only the branches,
i figured i can do a `LINQ` query on the `DataTable` and get distinct values.

boy, i was wrong... its not as simple i thinked it will be.

anyone can help me with this ? ( Lambda expression prefered )

edit:

if i wasnt clear, i need all the branches, from all the rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var rows = dataTable.AsEnumerable();
rows.Select(x => x["BRANCH"])
    .Union(rows.Select(x => x["BRANCH1"]))
    .Union(rows.Select(x => x["BRANCH2"]))
    .Union(rows.Select(x => x["BRANCH3"]));
```

This takes all the values from all the BRANCH columns in your table and uses `Union()` to a) join them into a single list and b) remove duplicates, giving you distinct values.

(NOTE: The `Union()` function removes duplicate values. In order to preserve duplicates, `Concat()` can be used in place of `Union()`)

--- EDIT ---

If you want to discard null values, user `Where()`, e.g.:-

```
var rows = dataTable.AsEnumerable();
rows.Select(x => x["BRANCH"])
    .Union(rows.Select(x => x["BRANCH1"]))
    .Union(rows.Select(x => x["BRANCH2"]))
    .Union(rows.Select(x => x["BRANCH3"]))
    .Where(x => x != null);
```

Comment: is there a possibility to discard null values?

Comment: note that in the original version of the answer I had a redundant call to Distinct() - I've removed this and added a note

Answer (score 1):

Define your own `IEqualityComparer`

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
   public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y) {
      // logic to distinguish the branches
      // this is just an example.  
      return x["BRANCH"] == y["BRANCH"] 
                && x["BRANCH1"] == y["BRANCH1"]
                && x["BRANCH2"] == y["BRANCH2"]
                && x["BRANCH3"] == y["BRANCH3"];

   }

   public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj) {
      // logic to distinguish the branches
      // this is just an example.
      return obj["BRANCH"].GetHashCode() +
                  obj["BRANCH1"].GetHashCode() +
                  obj["BRANCH2"].GetHashCode() +
                  obj["BRANCH3"].GetHashCode() ;
   }
}
```

and use it

```
var result = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Distinct(new MyComparer());
```

Comment: this will return only the first Branch what about the others?

Comment: @Dementic why do you say it will return only the first branch? `dataTable.AsEnumerable()` returns all datarows and Distinct() filters it down to unique ones as per the logic in the comparer.

Comment: since i dont see any reference to Branch1, branch2 etc ?

Comment: @dementic I just gave you a sample implementation. You can extend it to fit your logic. For eg. if you want to look at Branch and Branch1 then use `return x["BRANCH"] == y["BRANCH"] && x["BRANCH1"] == y["BRANCH1"]` and for GetHashCode, you can do something similar `return obj["BRANCH"].GetHashCode() + obj["BRANCH1"].GetHashCode()`

Comment: thank you for your time, but adam has answered the best as to what i asked.